# Maximum of two $C^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, continuity

Consider two $C^2$ functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that their derivatives satisfy $|\frac{df}{dx}| < e^{-x}$ and $|\frac{dg}{dx}| < e^{-x}$. Now I want to look at the continuous function $h = \text{max}(f, g)$. My question is, is $h$ necessarily absolutely continuous? If not, is it uniformly continuous?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Thoughtful questions, even homework-related, are welcome. However, you should not expect others to do your homework for you, and it's inappropriate to post your homework verbatim. (That may not be what you're doing, but all people here can go by is appearances.) Instead, please try to ask questions about specific places where you're stuck, or about particular concepts you don't understand. Here, have you thought about "worst cases" for the first derivatives, and what that might imply for the second derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is $h$ necessarily absolutely continuous? If not, is it uniformly continuous?

No for both. $h(x) = {1 \over 2}e^{-x}$ isn't uniformly continuous (its derivative is arbitrarily large).